# Slider is not working

Tags: html, slider

Link : https://phoenix-burn.github.io/jewelers/

My slider isn't working. I'm trying to make it work without JS.

Please help.

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer here if you post the script in the question itself and tag the specific language being used.

Comment: I got it working now. Thanks! I'll keep that in mind.